# Safe to store access token inside AsyncStorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking at storing a user access token within a React Native application. Initially I have been looking at Redux but instead I noticed that RN has `AsyncStorage`, now I am assuming that this in the case of IOS is the equivalent of `NSUserDefaults`. I may be wrong.

Would this be a good way to store the access token? I don't really want to go through the process of using Redux if I can help it for simple data storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AsyncStorage may not be the good solution, depend how your server handle your request.

However you can use Redux, and Redux-persist, using the transform parameter you can encrypt your data,

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#transforms

key encryption : https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt

You will still use AsyncStorage, but this time with encryption layer, to protect your data

Answer (score 3):

`Redux` is about data flow control. Not necessarily long term storage. If you want to persist redux data you will end up using `AsyncStorage` to do so.

AsyncStorage is sandboxed on non-jailbroken iOS devices. However, the data is not encrypted in any way.

A more secure solution for both platforms seems to be https://github.com/pradeep1991singh/react-native-secure-key-store

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncStorage` is not safe for sensitive information. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148714/is-react-natives-async-storage-secure)

In you use case, It will be better to use Firebase services to get token.
When app starts , you can do something like

```
var auth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      // Save it redux, or component state(in that case you need to do this in every component where token will be used

     // Unsubscribe from listener 
     auth()
    });
  } else {
    // User is not authenticated
    // Unsubscribe from listener 
     auth()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)

It's secure. Also, if i'm not mistaken (don't quote me on any of the following) you might be able to use this to give users the ability to log in to the same app/webapp on that device; or other devices. I also think you can share login details with other apps you've developed assuming these apps have the same domain in the bundle identifier.