# Security risk to sensitive large binary data in react native based apps stored in file system?

Tags: react-native, data-security

Are there any security risk to sensitive large binary data stored in file system when using react native framework in mobile apps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is React Native's Async Storage secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148714/is-react-natives-async-storage-secure)

Comment: @Dragomir Kolev Thanks for comment. I am storing some sensitive binary data on phone file system ( not using Async Storage which is key value storage system for small values) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing sensitive data in a binary file simply on the file system is problematic, seeing as any other program can read that file.

This has nothing to do directly with react-native, of course.

Comment: @NimrodArgoc Thanks for comment !!