# Is there any secure storage in react native other than AsyncStorage?

Tags: android, react-native, storage, asyncstorage

I want to store sensitive data locally in a React Native app.
AsyncStorage Is not suitable for storing sensitive information.

What can I use other than that?

Any help will be useful, Thanks.

Comment: Do you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214678/2266462 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need secure storage, you should probably look at os native mechanisms for that, one notable wrapper for those mechanisms is [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)